# HTML Preprocessor?

Tags: html, preprocessor, ssi

Is there a HTML preprocessor that can do simple page processing similar to [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes), but produce a static set of HTML pages?

Answer (score 4):

I think they are called pre-processors.

http://htmlhelp.com/links/preprocessors.html

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the wording really matters.

Answer (score 0):

It's a HTML Pre-processor.

More here : [htmlpp](http://legacy.imatix.com/html/htmlpp/#TOC1)